# How to attach screenshots for failed steps in cucumber-html-reporter using PUPPETEER?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, cucumberjs

**addCase.js:**

```
const {Given, When, Then, Before, After} = require('cucumber');

After(async function(scenario) {
    if (scenario.result.status === 'failed') {
        const screenShot = await this.page.screenshot();
        this.attach(screenShot,'image/png');
    }
});
```

**world.js:**

```
const expect = require("chai");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const {setWorldConstructor} = require("cucumber");
const helpers = require("../../helpers");
const config = require("../../config");

class CustomWorld{

    async launchBrowser(){
        this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: config.isHeadless,
        args: config.args,
        });
        this.page = await this.browser.newPage();
        await this.page.setViewport({ 
            width: config.viewportWidth,
            height: config.viewportHeight
        });
    }

}

setWorldConstructor(CustomWorld);
```

**ERROR:**

```
 TypeError: this.attach is not a function
```

- I tried with scenario.attach() - error: scenario.attach() not a function
- Also tried with simple storeScreenshot: false in my reporter.js (no change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the attach inside constructor:

```
function CustomWorld({ attach, parameters }) {
  this.attach = attach
  this.parameters = parameters
}
```

There are a few instructions on the docs: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/world.md

Then your call inside After (this.attach) will work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code in After hooks function:

```
if (!(scenario.result.status === 'failed')) return;
    try {
        const data18 = await driver.takeScreenshot();
        const image18 = Buffer.from(data18, 'base64');
        await this.World.attach(image18, 'image/png');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
```

This code will check whether scenario is failed. If it is failed, it will capture driver screenshot and will be attached to this.world object with the help of nodejs Buffer.